# Unknown filesystem after boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub

When I turn on my notebook Lenovo G580, it shows:

```
unknown filesystem
```

It's the same problem as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393502/windows-7-boot-error-unknown-filesystem-after-deleting-ubuntu). BUT, when I write

```
insmod normal
```

I get the message:

```
normal.mod file is not found
```

And I can't find it.

From [this solution](https://mintguide.org/system/186-repair-grub-error-unknown-filesystem-grub-rescue-in-linux-mint-pinguyos.html), after writing

```
ls (hd0,msdos6)/
```

he had a lot of files `etc`, `bin`, `boot`,... I only have two: `/Zoltan`, `/lost+found`, nothing else.

Boot from CD, USB -- not working.

Can someone write me the solution, what can I do? Thanks.

Comment: `(hd0,msdos6)` indicates a partition. The number `6` was correct for the solution author, but in your case it looks like there is your home partition under that number, not the one with Linux root filesystem. Try with numbers other (lower) than `6`. Under one of them there should be `boot/`.

Answer (score 0):

try this tutorial with **Boot Repair** utility
https://mintguide.org/tools/37-restore-grub-boot-loader-in-linux-mint-after-installation-reinstallation-windows.html

Comment: This may be a working solution for OP, still you should avoid giving answers with a link only. Read [this article](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer), "provide context for links" section, then edit your answer accordingly to make it (hopefully) high quality answer.